# Switch order for every row i and i+1 in column using every second i (i= 1, 3, 5, ....)

Tags: r, sorting

I have

```
d <- matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 1, 
            dimnames = list(c("a", "a1", "d", "e", "f", "f2"), NULL))
```

I want to sort the rows in the following order: `a1, a, e, d, f2, f`.

Notes:

- I am looking for a general solution. Of course, i know how to do it for this specific matrix.
- Rownames can be all kinds of names, so any string related operation doesnt work
- Matrix `d` will not have more than 16-20 entries. So dont worry about speed.
- The matrix has always an even number of rows.

Comment: `d[1:nrow(d) + c(1, -1), , drop = FALSE]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching every pair of rows gives us row numbers 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, etc. Hence, after the transformation the n-th row is the (n - (-1)^n)-th row in the original matrix.

Thus, the order of rows that you want is `1:nrow(d) - (-1)^(1:nrow(d))`:

```
d[1:nrow(d) - (-1)^(1:nrow(d)), , drop = FALSE]
#          [,1]
# a1  0.1228430
# a  -1.4051684
# e  -0.7928203
# d   1.3270429
# f2  0.3554126
# f  -1.1388026
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use a recycling logical vector to subset the row.names, alternate the names by first `rbind`ing it to a `matrix`, remove the `dim` attibutes with `c` (convert to a `vector`) and use that as row index

```
d[c( rbind(row.names(d)[c(FALSE, TRUE)], 
   row.names(d)[c(TRUE, FALSE)])),, drop = FALSE]
#          [,1]
#a1 -0.43704092
#a   0.41215035
#e   1.47443155
#d  -1.78087570
#f2 -0.01673482
#f   0.98952497
```